# Square Geometry with uneven formed Mesh

Tags: mesh, geometry

Is there a standardization method that helps adding geometry in form of an even wireframe with same-sized squares on to a mesh like the ones in this pictures:
[image]

The left geometry I had to add all manually and it's taking a lot of time.

I need even squares in order to UV-unwrap them and have undistorted displacement and texturing. Eventually these will be hedges like a boxwood.

[image]

Thanks in Regards,

F.Sterzik

Comment: I'm pretty sure that no matter how you unwrap it, there are going to be at least some seams. Why don't you build it in a more intuitive and easy way? I really don't see the advantage.

Comment: If I understand what you want to do, you shouldn't need to make squares. I think that placing seams appropriately and then just doing a simple unwrap will place your mesh properly.

Comment: But when I dont add geometry, I don't have the displacement, that empathizes the leafy structure. And its not about the place of the mesh @MartyFouts its abouzt the displacement map that gets distorted, when I have rectangles instead of squares.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I'm working with speheres now. They got a curve-mod and the displacement direction is not problematic. Rebuilding it in a more clever way sure did the trick :D